# To get the value from the paraller array and get to insert new value in next line

Tags: vb.net

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTZa5.jpg

> my code in add button

```
Dim item() As String = {"Hardisk", "Pen Drive", "Mouse", "Memory", "Keyboard"}
        Dim price() As Decimal = {200.0, 57.0, 45.0, 130.0, 58.0}
        Dim counter As Integer
        Dim items As String
        Dim quantity As String
        Dim findItem As String
        Dim find As Boolean = False

        lblOut.Text = "ITEM" & vbTab & "QTY" & vbTab & "PRICE" & vbTab & "SUBTOTAL" & vbNewLine

        items = txtItem.Text
        quantity = txtQuantity.Text
        findItem = items
        itemPrice = subtotal

        For counter = 0 To 4
            If findItem = lblOut.Text(counter) Then
                find = True
            End If
        Next

        lblOut.Text = lblOut.Text & items & vbTab & quantity & vbTab & itemPrice & vbTab & subtotal & vbNewLine
    End Sub
```

when i type my item in item box , it should search for the price in the price array and display into the textbox area for the PRICE and * with the quantity.
then i can add the next item for the new line.

> the problem i face is how to get the price form the item when i insert the item into the item area, the system check for the value that is set in the code.

> and how to go to next line when i want to add now value to the text box.

Comment: Please provide what is the problem and what you had done to solve the problem

Comment: Is there some requirement for the item and prices to be stored in separate collections?  Could be pretty simply solved by using a list of a custom class conatining the item name AND price, then you can just use linq to find the required item instance and retrieve it's price

Comment: And what exactly is the For counter = 0 To 4 Loop intended to do?  Doesn't seem to serve any purpose here

Comment: the for counter =0 to 4 is use for the cout loop for the item(4) and price(4), but i cant put the 4 inside it, it come with error when i want to input the value to the side

Comment: the counter will count from 0 to for for find the same statement

Comment: the question picture is in the first line